# Parallax background image scroll without using css background property

Tags: html, css, scroll

Is it possible to add parallax effect without using css `background` and `background-attachment` properties?

I have an `img` tag inside a `div` and want to add parallax scroll effect to the image, below is the code

```js
function resize_div()
{
    var image_height = $('.project-image img').height();

    var div_height = $('.project-image').height();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var window_width = $(window).width();

   
        $('.project-image').css('height', window_height - 80);
    
}

$(window).resize(function () {
        resize_div();
});
```

```css
.project-details
{
  width:100%;
}
.project-image{
  text-align:center
}
.project-description
{
  line-height:15px;
  margin:0 0 10px
}
.img-responsive
{
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-details">
  <div class="project-image">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350X225" class="img-responsive">
  </div>  
  <h1>
  Project Title
  </h1>
  <p class="project-description">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

**problem:** I can not put the image in the background of a `div`, so have to do it using the `img` tag only.

**Edit:** The image is horizontally centered in the `div`, and image and `div` sizes are updated on browser resize or mobile/tablet rotation using custom javascript. Have tried `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` but it doesn't seems to be working

[image: image with parallax effect]

**Edit-2** Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2owd5fm9/7/)

Comment: Check [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellarjs--webdesign-7307) out

Comment: @Tesseract thanks... Will check it out

Comment: can you post jsfiddle with something you have tried?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 have added the fiddle link, please check

Comment: should image be 100% width? and if so what should be height of visible part?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 yeah image height changes on window resize, so always full image and project title will be visible on every screen resolution

Comment: @NishantSolanki wait, i'm confused, how should parallax effect work on full size image? Do you want image to always be visible when page is scrolled?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 no no, when the page will be scrolled the image will have parallax effect. (i.e. the title and description will overflow from image). The image height js is only for initial page load. (i.e. it will always show whole image on any kind of resolution, but you can further scroll to view the description and at that time I need the parallax effect)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142596/discussion-between-nooorz24-and-nishant-solanki).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some time ago, I built these two examples with a parralax effect very similar to what you are looking for:

- [this example](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ObdywQ) using simple jQuery to update the position of the image and title on scroll
- [this example](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/LkBKOv) using only CSS with 3D positioning to simulate the parralax effect on the image

In any case, I don't think you need JS to size the image on load. Here is an example with your code using the jQuery code from the first pen I shared here :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var $window = $(window);
function scroll_elements(){
  var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
  var scrollLayer = scroll/1.4;
  
  $(".project-image").css(
    "-webkit-transform","translate3d(0," +  scrollLayer  + "px,0)",
            "transform","translate3d(0," +  scrollLayer  + "px,0)"
  );
}

$window.scroll(scroll_elements);
});
```

```css
.project-image {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.img-responsive {
  display:block;
  max-width:100%; 
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h1, .project-description {
  position:relative;
  max-width:500px;
  z-index:2;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-details">
  <div class="project-image">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350X225" class="img-responsive">
  </div>  
  <h1>
  Project Title
  </h1>
  <p class="project-description">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I kinda tried something else and in this particular case it works and possibly might be best solution:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#image2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  visibility:hidden;
}
#prl {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350X225" id="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350X225" id="image2">

<div id="prl">
  <p>
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv
  </p>
</div>
```

In this case no JS is needed, I'm just using same image 2 times: one for actual fixed disappearing one and one is just to reserve empty space

Comment: That is a very creative solution, but still in my case `position:fixed` is not the solution, as it ruins all the design. I will accept your answer if no any feasible solution found

Answer (score 2):

After some searching i found [this](https://codepen.io/RenanB/pen/GZeBNg)

```js
$('.img-parallax').each(function(){
  var img = $(this);
  var imgParent = $(this).parent();
  function parallaxImg () {
    var speed = img.data('speed');
    var imgY = imgParent.offset().top;
    var winY = $(this).scrollTop();
    var winH = $(this).height();
    var parentH = imgParent.innerHeight();


    // The next pixel to show on screen      
    var winBottom = winY + winH;

    // If block is shown on screen
    if (winBottom > imgY && winY < imgY + parentH) {
      // Number of pixels shown after block appear
      var imgBottom = ((winBottom - imgY) * speed);
      // Max number of pixels until block disappear
      var imgTop = winH + parentH;
      // Porcentage between start showing until disappearing
      var imgPercent = ((imgBottom / imgTop) * 100) + (50 - (speed * 50));
    }
    img.css({
      top: imgPercent + '%',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -' + imgPercent + '%)'
    });
  }
  $(document).on({
    scroll: function () {
      parallaxImg();
    }, ready: function () {
      parallaxImg();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:400,700);
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}
.block{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.block h2{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.img-parallax {
  width: 100vmax;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?image=1005" data-speed="-1" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed -1</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?image=1067" data-speed="1" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?gravity=center" data-speed="-0.25" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed -0.25</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?image=1080" data-speed="0.25" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed 0.25</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?random" data-speed="-0.75" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed -0.75</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?blur" data-speed="0.75" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed 0.75</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will integrate it with my code and let you know if it works or not.. thanks :)

Comment: this is not working in my case, i tried many different calculations in the JS you provided, also tried doing some CSS patches.. but no luck

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: I have created a fiddle, check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/2owd5fm9/6/

Comment: what you actually want to do ? in the fiddle has different code

Comment: this is the current code of the page, I want the image to stay like parallax when description is scrolled: https://jsfiddle.net/2owd5fm9/7/

Answer (score 2):

So this is the working example that was approved by **Nishant Solanki** and it should work in all browsers

```js
function myFunction() {
 speed = 0; 
  speed2 = -1;
  /**
  @ speed
  positive: moves up faster than background
  0: scrolls same as background
  negative: moves down faster
  -1: same as position: fixed
  try different ones to see it in action and you should figure it out
  
  P.S.
  you can apply different speeds to multiple alements to achieve what ever you desire
  */
 y = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  cont = document.getElementById("prl");
  cont.style.top = (0 - Math.round(y * speed)) +"px";
  img = document.getElementById("image");
  img.style.top = (0 - Math.round(y * speed2)) +"px";
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#prl {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="myFunction()">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/350X225" id="image">

<div id="prl">
  <p>
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsad
  sdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksda klsadsdf sfkdl ksdghjlsadv
  </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that "keep scrolling" bug that others might be experiencing on SO as I am. On jsFiddle it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use something as simple as `$(window).scroll` to detect window scroll and then simply `.addClass` `.removeClass` or `.toggleClass`- Then with the new styles attached with the *scroll*, simply change the position of your `img` element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('img').toggleClass('scrolled'); 
    })
})
```

---

```
.scrolled { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 777; // find correct value to use
  top: 102px; // adjust to customization
  left: 3px; // adjust to customization
}
```

**Note://** It is much cleaner practice to create this effect with a `background` image, and adjusting it's position with the `.scroll`. If you have an ability to rewrite some code to achieve this it could be worth it in the long wrong. If not, you should be able to use jQuery `.scroll` and `.toggleClass` with adjusting `z-index:` property and `position:` property. You should be using pure CSS3 for responsive layouts; if `position:` property isn't working, then there is a conflict somewhere else with likely too much CSS or JS for the relevant elements.

Comment: I had thought about this type of solution, but it is quite tough to maintain it in responsive design.. As the image size changes according to the screen size

Answer (score 2):

Try to **avoid `fixed` & `absolute`** in css . Hope you find it liberating.

```js
function myFunction() {
  fixIt = document.getElementById('project-image');
  fixIt.style.top = 2 * Math.round(document.body.scrollTop) + "px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#project-image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.project-description,
.project-details>h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}

.project-details {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="myFunction()">


  <div class="project-details">
    <div id="project-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350X225" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <h1>
      Project Title
    </h1>
    <p class="project-description">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      <br/>
      <br/> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      <br/>
      <br/> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I personally love this modern plugin. [Here](http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/)

Comment: @NishantSolanki I ran the snippet works fine. Is it not showing on your desktop ?

Comment: @NishantSolanki forget it anyway, i like the answer you chose even better than mine.